# Please assist with this code is failing to create the file with the files directories from the specified path in Python

Tags: python-3.x, path, pattern-matching

This is not creating the file it is intended to create and I do not know where I 
  went wrong.  It worked for the filename.endswith but the files criteria is not 
  always necessarily at the end all the time.

```
#Importing the modules needed
import os,fnmatch,functools,itertools
from pathlib import Path

#Specifying the file path and the working directory
relevant_file_path = os.fspath('c:/users\username\desktop\personal project')
included_extensions = ['*v15.02.*','*v16.01.*','*v17.01.*','*v13.01.*']

#Create a csv file to store the files directories
HOME = str(Path.home())
file_path = os.path.join(HOME,'test3.csv')

#Get everything split
def files_directories(root_path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(relevant_file_path):
        filter_partial = functools.partial(fnmatch.filter,filenames)
            for filename in itertools.chain(*map(filter_partial, included_extensions)):
                 with open(root_path,'a+') as f:
                     f.write(''.join((os.path.join(dirpath,filename),'\n')))
                 f.close()
files_directories(file_path)
```

Initially I had this code for the last section.

```
def files_directories(root_path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(relevant_file_path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(included_extensions):
                with open(root_path,'a+') as f:
                   f.write(''.join((os.path.join(dirpath,filename),'\n')))
                      f.close()
```

While the criteria was:included_extensions = ('v15.02.xls','v16.01.xls','v17.01.xls','v13.01.xls')

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect indenting for the f.close() in both instances and the f.write() in the first instance but in my code it is indented correctly. Thanks.

Comment: try changing this `relevant_file_path = os.fspath('c:/users/username/desktop/personal project/')`

Comment: I tried fiddling with that but that does not seem to be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a way around my initial problem but not sure if it is the best way.

```
from  __future__ import print_function
import os
from pathlib import Path

#Specifying the file path and the working directory
relevant_file_path = os.fspath('c:/users\username\desktop\personal project')
   included_extensions = ('v15.02.','v16.01.','v17.01.','v13.01.')

#Create a csv file to store the directories
HOME = str(Path.home())
print(HOME)
file_path = os.path.join(HOME,'test3.csv')


#Get everything split
def files_directories(root_path):
   for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.normcase(relevant_file_path)):
       for filename in filenames:
          for ext in included_extensions:
              if ext in filename.lower() and '.pdf' not in filename.lower():
                  with open(root_path,'a+') as f:
                       f.write(os.path.normcase(''.join((os.path.join(dirpath,filename),'\n'))))
                       f.close()
```